# how Does spring singleton bean behave for single method calls by multiple clients at same time?

Tags: spring, concurrency, singleton

By spring docs I found by default spring beans are singletons. How will spring behave if it has a   doSomethingMethod() { ... } and this method is being called by multiple clients at same time, will they share the same values being used in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just depends on the bean itself. There is no requirement that the bean be threadsafe, stateless, etc. If the bean isn't threadsafe, then sure, data races can result.

See also:
[what happens if more than one thread tries to access singleton object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322506/what-happens-if-more-than-one-thread-tries-to-access-singleton-object)

Not an exact duplicate since we're talking about slightly different senses of singleton here, but the same ideas apply.